# Google Map doesn't appear on Android device

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am able to display my Google Map properly in my MapView when I sign my application with my debug keystore. When I try and sign it with a release keystore, the map appears but as blank tiles, no map tiles.

How can I get my release build to show the maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your API keys.. if all looks fine and its still not working sign the app with a new key and corresponding new API key :-).

Comment: so is this a common thing then (map background all grey)? i thought that i was doing something wrong, but it may look like u have to keep registering new keys over and over just to get something to work.

Comment: I am not sure sure why this happens, but you don't need to do it over and over again, at least I did not :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your maps API key is matched with the keystore used to sign you app. Before signing your app with your release keystore, go over to http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html and generate a new API key.

Comment: I also found this link helpful: http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/06/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key/